# cdr string in ML language

Tags: ml

I try to find a library function in `ML` that equal to (cdr string) in `Scheme` (meaning (cdr abcd) = bcd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Asuming SML)

Another way is to convert the string to a list of chars ([explode](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/string.html#SIG%3aSTRING.explode%3aVAL)), then you have the option to take the head ([hd](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.hd%3aVAL)) or tail ([tl](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html#SIG%3aLIST.tl%3aVAL)), and then finally convert it back to a string ([implode](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/string.html#SIG%3aSTRING.implode%3aVAL)):

```
- (implode o tl o explode) "this is a string";
val it = "his is a string" : string
```

The string conversion functions can be found in the [String](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/string.html) module, and the head and tail functions can be found in the [List](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html) module

Obviously you can also use the substring method here, however in SML you have the [extract](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/string.html#SIG%3aSTRING.extract%3aVAL) function that are quite convenient in this case:

```
- String.extract("This is a string", 1, NONE);
val it = "his is a string" : string
```

Giving it the `NONE` argument makes it extract until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Ocaml dialect, you could use the standard [String](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/String.html) module with e.g.

```
let rest_str str = 
  let slen = String.length str in
  String.sub str 1 (slen-1)
;;
```